# Selecting an ROI automatically in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a image with a pattern in the middle and a white area surrounding it. I was hoping to cut out just the pattern in a rectangle while leaving out the excess unnecessary white area, that is, select a ROI automatically. Now I tried to do this by converting the image to grayscale and finding all the points with pixel values not equal to 255 with find.

After that I'm simply using the max and min values of x and y of the non white pixels to define the rectangle to be used by imcrop but for some reason it is not turning out quite like what I expected. Can anyone give me an idea on whats wrong?

Here's the code

```
function [] = Roi()

imgData=rgb2gray(imread('1.jpg'));

[A,B]=find(imgData~=255);

xmin=min(A);

xmax=max(A);

ymin=min(B);

ymax=max(B);

width = xmax - xmin;

height = ymax - ymin;

imgSelect = imcrop(imgData,[xmin,ymin,width,height]);

imshow(imgSelect);

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` returns result in the format **row** \ **column** and NOT X/Y. for your code to work you just need to change

```
[B, A] = find( imgData ~= 255 );
```

Comment: thanks..that solved one problem but for some reason I cannot get the proper ROIs this way.

Comment: @Roy what do you mean by "cannot get the proper ROIs"? what problem was solved and what problem are you still facing? Can you upload an example image, current extracted ROI and the desired ROI?

Comment: Never mind. The problem is for one particular dataset. Others are working fine. I'll check the dataset thoroughly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a more advanced method for Selecting an ROI automatically in matlab, see:
http://imageprocessingblog.com/region-of-interest-selection-for-saliency-maps/
(it has the full MATLAB code)